# laravel6: how to change references of a foreign key with migration

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-6

I have tried to change foreign key reference by dropforeign key.I think everything is ok but i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP
>   FOREIGN KEY teacher_schedule_calendars_product_id_foreign; check
>   that it exists (SQL: alter table teacher_schedule_calendars drop
>   foreign key teacher_schedule_calendars_product_id_foreign)

How can I solve it?

my migration code is :

```
Schema::table('teacher_schedule_calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['product_id']);
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id') ->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');  
});
```

firstly, I ave removed the foreign and then add references. but it did not work.

Comment: In your migration, you are dropping the foreign key before adding it, I can understand that the constraint already exist in the table but otherwise, this is the problem.

Comment: @Gamopo I cann't understand what you say. I have product_id as foreign key and the reference table was another table not courses. Now, I want to change it to reference the courses table. it add before in another migration when i create the teacher_schedule_calendars and shows in database.

Comment: Check if the constraint `teacher_schedule_calendars_product_id_foreign` exists in your database, maybe you erased it already and that's why it can't be found and `dropForeign(['product_id'])` will always return this error

Comment: Did you create the foreign key with `$table->foreign('product_id')` in a previous migration? If you created it with an alias, this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you created a foreign key on the `product_id` column in a previous migration and you simply want to renew it or replace it with a foreign key to another table. In this case, what you are attempting to do might be problematic due to the way how migrations work and how individual database grammatics translate the commands.

What you can do to mitigate the issue is splitting the commands into two `Schema::table($table)` blocks:

```
Schema::table('teacher_schedule_calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['product_id']));
});

Schema::table('teacher_schedule_calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');  
});
```

Comment: but I have to change the type to bigInteger by doctrine/dbal and then use your code.

Comment: Well, it might be that you need to do this step in a third closure. I think this is because Laravel executes all statements within one closure in one round-trip and it simply is a limitation of your DBMS.